# MOSFET Driver Base and Gate resistors and other input stage for PWM motor control

Tags: transistors, mosfet, pwm, mosfet-driver, gate-driving

I have the below basic pwm circuit for speed controller of a 12V ~10A motor -

[image: Circuit]

I have seen this circuit but am unsure of how to select base or gate resistors. These should be to protect the gate from voltage spikes as far as I understand? I am also interested in how this changes based on the different mosfets.

Also I have seen increased input stages, but am not sure if those are necessary or the purpose of them?

EDIT: I have updated as follows -

With the current measurement being done as below:
[image]

EDIT2: As pointed out the current sense has issues. The corrected input is here -
[image]

EDIT 3: I have further updated the circuit as follows utilizing a  [ZXCT1009](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZXCT1009.pdf) -
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bobflux covered the big issues, so just some extra notes:

- The proposed R<sub>B</sub> isn't very useful, as it's effectively divided by h<sub>FE</sub> and shows up as an equivalent value at the emitter output.
- D2 is incorrectly chosen.  For a 10A motor, assuming it could be operated at low RPM and full torque -- that is, dropping a couple volts (driven at low duty cycle) while at full amps -- there's nearly 10A average in the diode.  It's also a slow-recovery type, so will likely overheat even at fairly modest switching frequencies (~kHz?).  Something MBR1045(S) or the like would be a fine choice here.
- Also if it's going to be PWM, something should probably be watching motor current, so that PWM can be reduced or disabled if it should go too high.  This has saved endless numbers of transistors when a mechanism jams up, say.

Also make sure there's a substantial capacitor beside Q5, D4 and RC, probably 1000µF or more.  Keep the distance (placement and trace length) minimal between these components.

Regarding the current sense: put it in series with the motor itself.  As shown, it will only sense transistor current, so you can't tell how much current is circulating when the transistor is off.  Note SAC_OA must handle an input common mode voltage near +12V, which isn't obvious whether it can handle it, or if this implies its VCC will be above 12V.

There are two easy solutions to this:

1. Use a purpose-made current sense amplifier.  This includes a high-CMRR diff amp, and either a current output (e.g. ZXCT1107), or a ground referenced (e.g. INA180) or other referenced (e.g. INA199) voltage output. No need to match precision resistors, they're already trimmed for you.
2. Use an "Over The Top" type op-amp.  These are something like, self-powered from the inputs themselves, so they can still work even for Vin > Vcc; the downside is that current draw (input bias current), but they're carefully designed to use very little (~µA), certainly nothing you can't handle here.

Also, the diff amp shows a gain of 50, but RC already makes 1V at 10A (and dissipates 10W at that!); are you really expecting 50V full scale here?

Comment: Could you clarify the Rb that isn't useful? I have edited the original post with an updated circuit are you referring to R9 in that circuit?

Comment: @nk13 Rb in the first schematic, R9 in the second, R2 in Bob's.

Comment: Also, R10 is always on?

Comment: Oh yes of course, I have corrected R10. Not sure what I was thinking there. You are also correct on RC is dissipating too much power I will have to rethink that approach. Also, could you elaborate on the need for such a substantial 1000uF cap? Is this simply to beef up the supply for the potential start-up current spikes?

Comment: @nk13 Turn-off, more importantly. The transistor turns off in a fraction of a microsecond, in which time stray wiring inductance can generate flyback voltage. Without a capacitor shown, I assume the worst; it could be meters of wiring (several µH equivalent). Also, since Q10 is turned on so strongly (0.8mA Ib, easily able to draw >80mA Ic), Q6 is kind of redundant and can be replaced with say a BAT54H from E to B. This will drive the 100R gate resistor just fine (which limits gate current to 120mA anyway, not much different).

Answer (score 2):

Choose the switching frequency, for a motor it doesn't need to be very high.

Choose the switching time to be slow enough to avoid sharp edges which will make a lot of interference, but not too slow or your switching losses will increase. A few µs should work nicely.

Look at the gate charge of your MOSFET (or the gate charge curve) and choose a gate drive current to get to the charge that turns it on in the switching time you want. Since i=dq/dt, a current i during a time t moves a charge i.t. Knowing the current and the gate drive voltage (11V), you have your resistor value.

Next get rid of the driver that doesn't work. Since the micro outputs 3V3, the top transistor will lose one Vbe when on, which means it'll drive the FET with 2.7V on the gate. Either it won't turn on, or it will turn on partially, heat and smoke. So you need an extra transistor to translate 3V3 to 12V, for example:

[image]

This one also inverts the level, you can add another transistor to not invert it if you feel like it.

Too much current in the base will fry your bipolar transistors, and the base resistors protect against this. I used 1mA base current which should be fine, you can check the expected gate drive current of the MOSFET (see above) divided by the transistor current gain.

Comment: Or just get a FET driver IC if you can find one in stock somewhere.....